# Saving Chrome Packaged App data to storage on exit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome Packaged Web App with a text editor (CodeMirror), and I'd like to implement what (I thought!) was a simple feature:

> When the app is closed, it should remember the contents of the editor so that it's there when it is opened again.

Loading the text from storage is easy, and it works fine.

I just can't seem to make save on exit work. I'd like to save the code in chrome.storage.sync which means I can't just save every time a character is pressed - what I need to do is detect when the web app exits and then save the contents of the window.

I might just be doing something really stupid, but because I can't seem to debug what happens in background.js I have no idea - I can't even tell if my code is getting called when the window closes :(

Does anyone have an example of how to detect when a Packaged App's window is closed and then write something (anything!) into chrome.storage.sync? Hopefully I can work onwards from there!

(and sorry - I would have posted the code I used last time, but I can't find it now)

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried binding to `window.onbeforeunload`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload

Comment: So is it a Chrome (Packaged) App or a Web App hosted somewhere? The answer depends. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @Xan: The title says 'Chrome Packaged App' - but I'll update the main post as well.

Comment: @JonSnow `onbeforeunload` would be perfect, but I don't think it works on packaged apps - at least not according to [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/AAdzELbFlVE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you could always use `chrome.storage.local` as storage that you can write to very often, and then save to `sync` from your event page when the window closes.

You can listen to this from the event page with [`chrome.app.window.onClosed`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#event-onClosed).

---

You may want look into [`syncFileSystem` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/syncFileSystem) for saving editor files, since `storage.sync` has quite a low capacity.

Comment: Thanks - yes, that's perfect. When I update the local storage from inside the window, and then grab from local storage and write it into sync on exit (from background.js), it all works.

Comment: You (Gordon) may want to rethink your design. Exit is only one of the many occurrences when you want to ensure that the work is saved. You also have app crashes, browser shutdown, OS crash, power failure, and a few other things. Apps should have their work saved all the time so the user doesn't lose any work. One way is to install a handler for the idle event, and save when the user is idle for, say, 15 seconds. Or, save after X number of changes have been made. (These are only examples.) Think about how Google's Keep app works.

Comment: @MarcRochkind Do propose something better than saving to `storage.local` often (maybe after every character input). I don't think app authors should be concerned with more resiliency than this.